# Creating Code First 1:1 relationship in entity framework results in two foreign key fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a 1:1 relationship between two Entity Framework code-first models between Customer and MembershipType. Their models are:

**Customer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set; }

        public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Membership Type")]
        public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
        public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MembershipType.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class MembershipType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public short SignupFee { get; set; }
        public byte DurationInMonths { get; set; }
        public byte DiscountRate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And when the migration is ran it results in the following Customer table:
[image: Resulting Customers Table]

Why does this happen? It's causing issues when trying to use an Html helper to create a drop down box, as when it saves it wants to put the data into the MembershipTypeId column but it appears entity is actually using the MembershipType_Id column.

Comment: Why do you have public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }? Using coding-first you generate de relation only with the object MembershipType .

Comment: I'll give it a shot right now! I used byte MembershipTypeId because my professor told me to tbh. Sorry, I was american higher learning'd.

Comment: Don't waste your time. `one-to-one` with explicit FK property (like yours `public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }`) is not supported.

Comment: But without any fluent configuration the implied relationship from your model is `many-to-one`. EF is creating another FK field because you used `byte` for the FK while the PK type of the referenced entity is `int`. If you change it to `public int MembershipTypeId { get; set; }`, EF will use your property (but the relationship still will be `many-to-one` :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the following code:

```
namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set; }



        [Display(Name = "Membership Type")]
        public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
        public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }


     public virtual  MembershipType MemshipType { get; set; }
    }


    public class MembershipType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public short SignupFee { get; set; }
        public byte DurationInMonths { get; set; }
        public byte DiscountRate { get; set; }

       public virtual  Customer  customer{ get; set; }
    }

}
```

For More info and other ways of doing the same, kindly refer this useful link:http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Hope it will  be helpful

Thanks

Karthik